# Linking pdf which is stored on local server to web map made with qgis2web

Tags: qgis, qgis2web

I have a QGIS project that I have linked pdf's to shapefiles using a file directory field with a "attachment"widget. I have it set up so when I click on the shape in my project, the link pops up which will bring me to the relevant pdf. I tried to export this project using qgis2web, but where the link normally is, there is just a question mark.

Any way to have that link in a web map? My intent is to not put the web map online, but have it on the internal server for co-workers to use.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How does the full URL look like (roughly, do not post private details)?

Comment: //server/ and then the folder in the server the pdfs are housed

Comment: Does it work with `file:///server/...`?

Comment: file://server/... worked when i changed it to text edit :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because qgis2web interprets QGIS "Attachment" fields as images. If you make the fields text, rather than attachments, it will try to recognize hyperlinks and make them clickable.

One thing I've run into, though, is that links to `file://` addresses often fail in browsers these days, so even if the above works - in other words, it produces the link correctly - the links still might not work in a browser. Depending on which browser you need this to work in, there might be registry hacks to allow file:// links, but that may or may not be a solution for you (ie do you have access to the registry on every machine which will view the webmap?).