# How to include a PDF for displaying or downloading in QField

Tags: qgis, pdf, hyperlink, qfield

What I am looking for:

In a point-layer I would like to add a PDF (stored in OneDrive) that can be opened in Qfield while doing fieldwork.

What I did so far:

I created two fields named 'attachment' (widget type: attachment) and 'url' (widget type: text) I transferred the URL via field calculator to the attachment, because i wasn't able to fill in the URL directly to the default path (my workaround, maybe there is a better solution for this)

What works so far:

In QGIS, when i open the attributetable it shows me the PDF and I can even click on the link and it opens the file in the browser - thats exactly what I want.

[image: what it looks like in QGIS - pretty good for my purpose]

What doesn't work:

When I export the file to QField and I open the attribute table there, the PDF is not shown and neither is the path. In the field 'url' (widget type: text) the path is shown but cannot be selected and thus not be opened in the browser.

[image: what it looks like in QField]

I couldn't find a related post until now. How can I make this work?.

Answer (score 0):

Filepaths (local ones or weblinks) in attachement widgets are recognized by QField (at least since 1.9) and available as read-only hyperlinks.

[image: localfile]

[image: weblink]

Beeing able to edit them would be a nice enhancement, but is not yet possible.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add some details to @signedav's answer since I struggled a bit with the same issue: How to include a default pdf-file to an attribute in my form.
This should do the trick:

1. Create a subfolder 'pdf' in your QGIS project folder (where your qgs/qgz-file is saved)
2. Add the pdf-file (sub.pdf) in the pdf-folder just created
3. In the form, set an attribute to be an attachment-widget and set the pdf-file as default value ('pdf/sub.pdf')
   [image]
   **4. Add 'pdf' as an attachment-directory** in the [QFieldSync settings](https://docs.qfield.org/how-to/pictures/?h=atta)
   [image]
   [image]
4. Create a QFieldCloudProject
   [image]
   In this way the pdf-folder is included in the Cloud project-folder on the computer.
   [image]
5. On tablet in QField: Download the project and open it. The pdf-file can be clicked and opened in a PDF Reader-app on the mobile device.
   [image]

Answer (score -1):

If you just need it as reference material I can suggest instead of using QField create a webmap with the qgis2web pluggin. I have done exactly what you want with a web map so that you can tap on your point and have a link to a .pdf in it. I had some help creating this in the linked post bellow. Only problem with a web map is that to my knowledge you cannot add or edit data in a web map. But like I said above, if you are just using it for reference it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and your help.The point is, that I need th have the possibility to edith the points of the layer. Either move them around or change an attribute of the layer. Can you however post the link you were talking about? Would be interessting to learn more about implementing webmaps.

Comment: Sorry about that! I thought I had it posted! See bellow: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/348983/linking-pdf-which-is-stored-on-local-server-to-web-map-made-with-qgis2web/349050#349050